# How to grant quota on a temporary tablespace to a user

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to create a user in Oracle 12c with a default temporary tablespace and with a quota for that tablespace.

My statement is:

```
CREATE USER test_user2
IDENTIFIED BY "pass1234"
DEFAULT TABLESPACE TEMP_WORK_TS
QUOTA 100M ON TEMP_WORK_TS
QUOTA 100M ON TEMP_TEST_01
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP_TEST_01
PROFILE DEFAULT_PROFILE
ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

But I get error:

> ORA-30041: Cannot grant quota on the tablespace

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/users.htm#DBSEG99778) shows a quota being assigned for a user's temporary tablespace.

Why does my statement doing the same thing get that error?

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a documentation bug. That example goes back at least to [Oracle 9i documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/users.htm#15245), so it may predate true temporary tablespaces.

[Also from the 12c documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/users.htm#CIHDCDBJ):

> You can assign each user a tablespace quota for any tablespace (except a temporary tablespace).

And the [text for ORA-30041](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/e29250.htm#ORA-30041) is:

> **ORA-30041: Cannot grant quota on the tablespace**
>   **Cause**: User tried to grant quota on an undo or temporary tablespace
>   **Action**: Check the tablespace name and reissue the command

It's said that since 10g, but the 9i version only referred to undo tablespaces. The behaviour seems to have changed, and the example just has hasn't been updated to reflect that.

So you can't grant that temporary tablespace quota. Just omit it from the create user statement. A quota only really makes sense for permanent extents anyway, and you don't know how much temporary space the optimiser might need to allocate for queries the user might run.

Comment: Many thanks Alex. Is there any way that I can restrict the user from using full temp tablespace? I mean I just want to restrict the user from consuming full space of temp tablespace.

Comment: Not that I know of, I don't think the resource manager lets you limit that specifically, but other limits might be more appropriate anyway. Temporary space is there to be used though. You could assign a small temp TS (which is set to not autoextend), but you'll just end up with an unable-to-extend exception if they do something excessive, and you'll still have the potential for them to affect other users' queries. You might be better asking about that on [dba.se].

Comment: Thanks Alex for quick response.